# AngularJS Array keeps on updating after ngClick

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a lot of array stuff going on, I've managed to shorten it off and I've uploaded it on the link below.
http://www.asaadmahmood.com/asaad/edited/edit.php

You can view the code for my angular, the code is very short and can be seen in the file below:
http://www.asaadmahmood.com/asaad/edited/js/main.js

What I'm doing is I'm pushing the people titles inside an array called EventGroups.list; The reason I'm making this an array of objects is that I have a bunch of values and I need to access them by their specific key.

The checkboxes I click are added/subtracted from another array `selectedGroupCri` on `ng-click` on the checkbox themselves.

The issue here is that when I add an object inside the array the object gets added and the people get added too, however after adding them the people are linked by the checkboxes above even after being edited into the array. I would like to find a proper way of adding the people and then closing this link off between the two so when a person has created the object, those checkboxes can no longer interfere with it.

My markup is like this:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="EventCriCtrl">
    <h3><label class="checkbox__label">Select people <span>*</span></label><br></h3>
    <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="criterion in groupCriteria">
        <label style="font-size: 15px">
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{criterion.title}}" ng-checked="selectedGroupCri.indexOf(criterion) > -1" ng-click="toggleCriSelection(criterion)">
            <div class="value">{{criterion.title}}</div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" ng-click="groupAdd()" class="btn btn-default" value="Add Group">
</div>

<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
    <p>{{group}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What about using a condition? i.e. `if(!isGroupAdded() { .. })`

Comment: The condition would rather be `!isPersonAdded` The thing is that a user can add as many groups as he wants, and as you can see on the page, no matter how many groups I add by clicking the add group button, the checkboxes are still linked. If I do go forward with that method then I would have to check for that !isPersonAdded condition for all those groups that have been added. Which would definitely affect the performance of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the "Add Group" button is clicked, you are calling the groupAdd() function. This presumably is defined in your EventCriCtrl controller. I suspect that in this function, you are pushing the current checked array into the $scope.groups array. However, this is just pushing a pointer to the object into the array. Instead, you need to make a copy of the array with Angular.copy() so that a deep copy is created that is no longer bound to the checkboxes.

If you're currently doing something like this:

```
 $scope.groups.push($scope.selectedCheckboxes);
```

Then you should change to something like:

```
 $scope.groups.push(angular.copy($scope.selectedCheckboxes));
```

if you post your controller code, I can see if this is the exact issue, and update the code accordingly.

UPDATE (Just looked at the source of the code you linked):

Where you have (in the $scope.groupAdd definition):

```
var criteria = $scope.selectedGroupCri;
```

change to:

```
var criteria = angular.copy($scope.selectedGroupCri);
```

Comment: My controller codes and my main.js file can be seen here:
http://www.asaadmahmood.com/asaad/edited/js/main.js

Comment: I would just like to know, will this angular.copy make my app slow. I mean a user will be able to add as many groups as he want in the app, so will that effect the performance of the app seeing as a copy would be generated everything a user adds a group.

Comment: As long as you don't have groups of thousands, you shouldn't see any issue. Given the size of the objects, this is very light weight. If you see any performance issues (I'd be shocked), then you could alternately create a new group array every time and load each up with pointers to the criterion that are selected (as opposed to a full deep copy including the criterion content).However, I'm only answering that from a theoretical technical standpoint -- I seriously doubt you'll have any problems as-is with the deep copy.